# RestResource Get URL

Tags: webservices, rest, restresource

I have a Rest Web Service class that exposing Get Function.
I am trying to get the entire URL of the request to save it in logs.

According to the [Salesforce Documentation](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm) I could get it, without beginning of the URL, with :

```
req.requestURI
```

But when I use it, I only get 'Account/' if I take as example the Get function in the documentation, without base URL and without parameters.

So the question is how I can get the entire URL of the Request including base URL and Parameters?

for example:  `https://myDev.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/GetAccountInfo?IdNumber=1561&AddressId=53812245&Apartment=8`

Comment: This is covered in the [docs](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_restrequest.htm). What have you tried? Where are you stuck?

Comment: I want to get the all URL : https://myDev.my.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/GetAccountInfo?IdNumber=1561&AddressId=53812245&Apartment=8 
but I get only : /GetAccountInfo

Comment: that is what I did, wanted to know if there is a short way.